# std::unique_ptr, pimpl and object lifetime

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior

The following example compiles with both gcc 11 on Linux (GNU STL) and clang 12 on FreeBSD (Clang STL). On Linux, it runs and prints values 1 and 2. On FreeBSD, it prints value 1 and then crashes with a SEGV. I don't **quite** understand the object lifetimes -- so the whole thing may be UB and the runtime behavior might not be relevant. I do know that the **implementation** of `std::unique_ptr` between those two STLs differs in an important way: Clang STL resets the internal pointer of a `std::unique_ptr` to `nullptr` at the start of the destructor, while GNU STL leaves the pointer alone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct C {
    struct Private {
        C* m_owner;
        int m_x;
        Private(C* owner) : m_owner(owner), m_x(0) {}
        ~Private() { m_owner->cleanup(); }
        void cleanup() { std::cout << "Private x=" << ++m_x << '\n'; }
    };
    
    std::unique_ptr<Private> d;
    C() { d = std::make_unique<Private>(this); }
    ~C() = default;
    void cleanup() { d->cleanup(); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    C c;
    c.cleanup(); // For display purposes, print 1
    return 0; // Destructors called, print 2
}
```

Output on FreeBSD:

```
Private x=1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and a snippet of backtrace:

```
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x8)
    frame #0: 0x00000000002032b4 a.out`C::Private::cleanup() + 52
a.out`C::Private::cleanup:
->  0x2032b4 <+52>: movl   0x8(%rax), %esi
```

My reason for thinking this might be UB is this:

- at `return 0`, `c`'s lifetime is ending.
- the destructor `~C()` runs. Once the body (defaulted) of the destructor is done, the lifetime of the object is over and using that object is UB.
- now the destructors for sub-objects (member-objects?) of the object run.
- the destructor `~std::unique_ptr<Private>` runs. It runs the destructor for the held object.
- the destructor `~Private()` uses a pointer to a no-longer-alive object `m_owner` to call a member function.

I'd appreciate an answer that points out if this understanding of object lifetimes is correct.

If it's not UB, then there's a separate quality-of-implementation issue (or I should check the d-pointer before calling methods on it, but that seems a bit derpy for a pimpl; then we get `if(d)d->cleanup()` which is needed with one STL implementation and which is a useless check in another).

In the interest of posing a single question: does this code exhibit UB in the statement `m_owner->cleanup()` (line 9) during the destruction of object `c` ?

Comment: `My reason for thinking this might be UB is this:` yes. `Once the body (defaulted) of the destructor is done` well, it's https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime - `The lifetime of an object ends when:  ... the destructor call **starts**`

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is a RAII class, which handles the lifetime for the (dynamically allocated) object for you. Why are you writing an extra wrapper around it to do the same? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JHBonarius it's existing code where I'm trying to fix the crash; to me it looks like it was partly-pimpl'ed, leaving some method definitions in the original class rather than moving them to the private class. Then there's this cleanup function that needs to run on destruction, and so the private class calls back to the owner, since that's easiest ..

Comment: So the constructor of `C` should do something: Either doing some cleanup on its own. Actively calling `d.reset()` there with keeping the cleanup calls would lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the lifetime of the object that `m_owner` refers to has already ended and it's destructor call completed when `m_owner->cleanup();` is called. The call is therefore UB.